# Seven boys and five girls are seated around a circular table with 12 chairs. Prove that there are two boys sitting opposite one another.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Seven boys and five girls are seated (in an equally spaced fashion) around a circular table with 12  chairs. Prove that there are two boys sitting opposite one another.

I used 'G' for girls and 'B' or boys. I drew 7 B's and 5 G's in a circle, alternating G's:

B - G - B - G - B - G - B - G - B - G - B - B

I understand this is a pigeonhole principle problem, but I'm not sure how to show that this is true.

You have the sets: {B,G} , {B,G} , {B,G} , {B,G} , {B,G} , {B,B}

After the hints given, this is my solution: Given a circular table with 12 chairs, there are 6 pairs of individuals siting opposite each other. There are only 5 girls, but there are 7 boys. Therefore, by the pigeonhole principle, one of the pair of individuals must be 2 boys.

Comment: @1202487 https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2026928/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail#comment_10057598

Answer (score 7):

HINT: There are $6$ pairs of individuals sitting opposite each other. There are $7$ boys.

Note that it does little good to look at a particular arrangement of boys and girls, since the question is about all possible arrangements.

Comment: I hope my answer is not too close. I tried to make it different, but there are not too many ways :-)

Comment: @robjohn: The upvote is from me.

Comment: Your answer is more pigeon-holy.

Comment: @robjohn: True, but yours is elegant, and I’ve never been a fan (to put it mildly) of restricting allowable arguments.

Comment: Bah! Both of you get an up-vote.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose not, then each boy has a girl sitting opposite him.